# How to get "PartyAndCertificate" of a specific node participant?

Tags: corda

In my flow, I want to call a predefined subflow

```
    fun generateSpend(services: ServiceHub,
                     tx: TransactionBuilder,
                     amount: Amount<Currency>,
                     ourIdentity: PartyAndCertificate,
                     to: AbstractParty,
                     onlyFromParties: Set<AbstractParty> = emptySet()): Pair<TransactionBuilder, List<PublicKey>> {
       return generateSpend(services, tx, listOf(PartyAndAmount(to, amount)), ourIdentity, onlyFromParties)
   }
```

in https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/finance/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/finance/contracts/asset/Cash.kt

My question is how I can get "PartyAndCertificate" of a specific node participant in my flow, in which is required by ourIdentity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways:

- You can get your own node's `PartyAndCertificate` using the `FlowLogic.ourIdentityAndCert` method
- You can get the `PartyAndCertificate`s of all the nodes on the network using:

  ```
  serviceHub.networkMapCache.allNodes.flatMap { it.legalIdentitiesAndCerts }
  ```
- You can get the `PartyAndCertificate`s of a specific node on the network using:

  ```
  serviceHub.networkMapCache.getNodeByLegalName(CordaX500Name("ANodeOrg", "", "GB"))
      ?.legalIdentitiesAndCerts
      ?: throw FlowException("Party not found on network.")
  ```

Note that as of Corda 3.1, each node on the network only has one legal identity (i.e. the `legalIdentitiesAndCerts` list will contain exactly one item per node).